# Naming convention for non-static final variables in an enum in Java

Tags: java

```java
public enum Rarity {

    COMMON("Common", 1000, 1, new Color(0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1)), //Bronze color
    UNCOMMON("Uncommon", 100, 1.05, new Color(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1)), //Silver color
    RARE("Rare", 10, 1.10, new Color(1, 0.84, 0, 1)); //Gold color

    public final String name;
    public final int maxNumberCards;
    public final double performanceBoost;
    public final Color color;

    Rarity(String name, int maxNumberCards, double performanceBoost, Color color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.maxNumberCards = maxNumberCards;
        this.performanceBoost = performanceBoost;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

I have this enum in Java and I was wondering but couldn't find an answer, should my variables be named like this or in uppercase like constants ? They aren't static so it makes me wonder.

Comment: Your variables should be `private` and must not be `final`. The naming convention is the same as in other classes

Comment: @Jens The non-static fields can and should be final.